# Wordpress site broken after Apache vhost setting

Tags: wordpress, apache, host, vhosts

I had a working wordpress site accessible by http://localhost/wp corresponding to the directory /Library/WebServers/Documents/wp. Since I desired to have my wordpress site accessible by http://wordpress without moving the wordpress directory I decided to set a new host in /etc/private/hosts where I added the entry:

```
127.0.0.1   wordpress
```

Then I was able to access the site with http://wordpress/wp. To avoid the 'wp' part of the URL I decided to use Apache virtual hosts by adding in /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf the following block:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/wp"
    ServerName wordpress
    ServerAlias wordpress
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/wordpress"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/wordpress" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I restarted Apache and trying to access the site by using the URL http://wordpress I was able to see the written part of the first page but **no images** and all the **links where broken**.
Checking out the links I see that the URL they are pointing still contains the 'wp' part I was trying to avoid.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your database, all of the URLs still have the /wp/ in them. Changing your Apache config did not change this. The easiest way to do this is to use wp-cli (http://wp-cli.org) to do a search and replace on your WordPress database.

**BACKUP YOUR DATABASE BEFORE PROCEEDING**

```
wp search-replace 'http://wordpress/wp/' 'http://wordpress/' --dry-run
```

Assuming you have installed wp-cli and named it wp, the command above will show you all the changes it would make to remove the /wp/. from your URLs.

Once you are happy that it is changing the correct things, remove ``--dry-run` and it will actually make the changes for you.

wp-cli is a powerful tool. We use it for a lot of tasks at http://getpantheon.com and I use it to do a lot of maintenance work on all my personal WordPress sites.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't use the wp-cli tool but you pointed me in the right direction, the db. In the wordpress db table wp_options I found under the column option_name the values 'siteurl' and 'home' both set to http://wordpress/wp. I deleted the 'wp' part and then I was able to see correctly the first page but still observed the problem with the links. I solved finally the links issue by modifying the .htaccess file where I removed all 'wp' occurrences.